# Is it possible to refresh a page or disable the next text field if the user get the else statement?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
 <?php
    require_once("dbcon.php");

    if(!empty($_POST["username"])) {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE userName='" . 

    $_POST["username"] . "'");

    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $user_count = $row[0];

      if($user_count>0) {

          echo "<span class='status-not-available'> Username registered</span>";

      }else{
          echo "<span class='status-available'> Username not Available.</span>"; 
   }

   }

?>
```

this is my code thank you!

Comment: Yes, but you need to use javascript or redirect to the same page using PHP.

Comment: how in php?? thankyou

Comment: Where is your problem ? It's not clear. Your else statement should work for this statement. What's the problem here now ?

Comment: @MaxMastalerz - The user has a [tag:Javascript] tag in the question, not seeing what the funny part is and why you told them no and laughed at them when the answer is obviously yes

Comment: i want to disable the next text field if the user get the username not available, , or refresh the page to clear the text fields of the form

Comment: What's the problem in your script now ? Is it not working ? Is it giving any error ?

Comment: no error mr, but i want to refresh ar disable the next textbox, for not continuing , if the user get error ( username not available") the page will reload or disable the next textbox thankyou

Comment: Where are your next textbox ? Add condition if($user_count<=0) { echo "my next textbox" ;  }

Comment: <div class="control-group">
   <tr><td> <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail"><font color="yellow">BANK</label>

    <div class="controls">
 <td><select class="span2" name="bank"value="" required>
 <option>BCA</option>
    <option>MANDIRI</option>
    <option>BRI</option>
    <option>BNI</option>
    <option>DANAMON</option>
 <option>CIMB</option>

Comment: or we can make it as, disable the submit button so the form will not continue

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once("dbcon.php");

if(!empty($_POST["username"])) {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE userName='" . 

$_POST["username"] . "'");

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$user_count = $row[0];

  if($user_count>0) {
      die("{success:true, message: \"Username registered.\"}");

  }else{
      die("{success:true, message: \"Username not Available.\"}");
   }

   }

?>
```

Then you can catch the success value to define your textfield

Edit:
put this to your js :

```
var Stat = form.reader.jsonData.Message;
```

This 'Stat' will gives you themessage

Comment: success false not working dear?. it print only this "{success:false, message: \"Username not Available.\"}

Comment: or can i make it like alert box?